# How to split string and remove incomplete rows in CSV using Python?

Tags: python, html, csv, scrapy

Currently, I'm using Scrapy in Python to extract a html table from a website to write to a csv. I've managed to get the data I want, however the final format is not 100% what I need. The link is https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/schedule/Premier-League-Scores-and-Fixtures and this is my code:

```
import scrapy

class XGSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'expectedGoals'

    start_urls = [
        'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/schedule/Premier-League-Scores-and-Fixtures',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="sched_ks_3232_1"]//tbody/tr'):
            yield {
                'home': row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first(),
                'homeXg': row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first(),
                'score': row.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract_first(),
                'awayXg': row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract_first(),
                'away': row.xpath('td[8]//text()').extract_first()
            }
```

So to save the file into a csv I type this into the terminal:

```
scrapy crawl expectedGoals --output exG.csv
```

I get this csv:

```
home,homeXg,score,awayXg,away
Liverpool,1.9,4–1,1.0,Norwich City
West Ham,0.7,0–5,3.3,Manchester City
Burnley,0.7,3–0,0.8,Southampton
Watford,0.9,0–3,0.7,Brighton
Bournemouth,1.0,1–1,1.0,Sheffield Utd
Crystal Palace,0.8,0–0,0.9,Everton
Tottenham,2.6,3–1,0.6,Aston Villa
Newcastle Utd,0.5,0–1,0.9,Arsenal
Leicester City,0.6,0–0,0.6,Wolves
Manchester Utd,2.1,4–0,0.8,Chelsea
,,,,
Arsenal,1.0,2–1,1.3,Burnley

.
.
.
.
```

I'd like to split the `score` into `homeScore` and `awayScore` fields using `-` as a delimiter. Also, I want to figure out how to delete a row completely if the fields are empty, such as above. I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: Which field is empty? I cannot find any? is it possible to provide the csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,load and convert your csv to Pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("exG.csv")
```

To surrogate the csv, I am creating artificial data_csv and convert it into Pandas

```
data_csv = [{'home': 'Liverpool', 'score': '4-1', 'away': 'Norwich City'},
            {'home': 'West Ham,', 'score': '9-5', 'away': "Manchester City"},
            {'home': 'Burnley', 'score': '3-0', 'away': 'Southampton'}]



df = pd.DataFrame(data_csv)
```

> I'd like to split the score into homeScore and awayScore fields using `-` as a delimiter

```
df[['homeScore', 'awayScore']] = df['score'].str.split("-", expand=True)
```

Comment: If my or another [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) was helpful, don't forget accept it. Thanks